# Converting string array to int with a delimiter

Tags: java, regex

I can't figure out why I'm getting a null pointer exception.  I'm trying to convert a line numbers that the user enters after a prompt, and I want to deliminate it either a space " " a comma "," or a comma and a space ", ".

Here's my code, I'm getting a null pointer exception on the nums[i]=Integer.parseInt(holder[i]); line.  I just can't figure out why.

```
String again="n";
    int[] nums = null;

    do {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a sequence of integers separated by a combination of commas or spaces: ");
        String in=scan.nextLine();
        String[] holder=in.split(",| |, ");

            for (int i=0; i<holder.length; i++) {

                nums[i]=Integer.parseInt(holder[i]);
                System.out.print(nums[i]);
            }


    }
    while (again=="y");
```

Ok Thanks everyone, I got it working by initializing the length of the nums array to the length of the holder array as suggested in the accepted answer.  Like this:

```
int[] nums = new int[holder.length];
```

I have a second question though, as my regex seems to be failing, I can get it to read if delineated by "," or by " " but not by ", "  any ideas?

Here's my error:

```
Enter a sequence of integers separated by a combination of commas or spaces: 
    1, 2, 3
    Exception in thread "main" 1java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at SortComparison.main(SortComparison.java:20)
```

Comment: You have not mentioned size of array?

Comment: do you think if I use a list instead it'll work without having to declare the size?

Comment: Yes, a list will work, but you still have to initialize it: `List<int> nums = new List<int>();` For this purpose, though, an array will work just as well, because you know the size (its the length of your string array).

Comment: @drewmore I think it is Integer as it doesn't accept premitive type

Comment: @Pragnani is absolutely correct.

Comment: I actually have a second question regarding the regex, I can get it working for "," and for " " but not for ", "  I'll edit it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your null pointer exception is caused by the fact that you have initialized the nums array to null, then try to "point" to it in your for loop. You can lose `int[] nums = null` and add:

```
int[] nums = new int[holder.length];
```

immediately before the for loop (after you've created the holder array, obviously).

Comment: I wound up doing this because it's a simple program and this is easier to manage than a list.

Comment: Indeed it is. In general, though, lists are very useful. I use them many times more often than I use arrays nowadays.

Comment: I may wind up changing it, I haven't used them very often, but I'm gonna eventually have to put this into a sort and it might be easier to handle on larger inputs

Comment: Possibly, but you can sort arrays fairly easily too. Lists primarily become useful when you don't know how large they will need to be. As long as this code remains basically the same (i.e. as long as your array will always be coming from a single line of user input), an array will suit you just fine, because you'll always know exactly how big the array needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

You have set

```
int[] nums = null;
```

and then try to access

```
num[i]
```

which gives you the NullPointerException. You first need to contruct the array to hold the required number of elements:

```
int[] nums = new int[holder.length]
```

Answer (score 0):

You better print your `holder[i]` before parsing it into an Integer, to see what's in it.
I am guessing that `holder[i]` is not having a valid value for an Integer.

Comment: Would that result in a NullPointerException, though?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I can see that `i` is less than `length` for sure, and he claims that the line which throws an exception is there. So it could cause an exception; not `NullPointerException` though.